# Find all nulls with SQL query over pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of `StructField` with a mixed schema (`DoubleType`, `StringType`, `LongType`, etc.).

I want to 'iterate' over all columns to return summary statistics.  For instance:

```
set_min = df.select([
        fn.min(self.df[c]).alias(c) for c in self.df.columns
    ]).collect()
```

Is what I'm using to find the minimum value in each column.  That works fine.  But when I try something designed similar to find Nulls:

```
set_null = df.filter(
       (lambda x: self.df[x]).isNull().count()
).collect()
```

I get the `TypeError:  condition should be string or Column` which makes sense, I'm passing a function.

or with list comprehension:

```
set_null = self.df[c].alias(c).isNull() for c in self.df.columns
```

Then I try pass it a SQL query as a string:

```
set_null = df.filter('SELECT fields FROM table WHERE column = NUL').collect()
```

I get:

```
ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 14)\n\n== SQL ==\nSELECT fields FROM table WHERE column = NULL\n--------------^^^\n"
```

How can i pass my function as a 'string or column' so I can use `filter` or `where` alternatively, why wont the pure SQL statement work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are things wrong in several parts of your attempts:

- You are missing square brackets in your list comprehension example
- You missed an L in `NUL`
- Your pure SQL doesn't work, because `filter`/`where` expects a where clause, not a full SQL statement; they are just aliases and I prefer to use `where` so it is clearer you just need to give such a clause

In the end you don't need to use `where`, like karlson also shows. But subtracting from the total count means you have to evaluate the dataframe twice (which can be alleviated by caching, but still not ideal). There is a more direct way:

```
>>> df.select([fn.sum(fn.isnull(c).cast('int')).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

This works because casting a boolean value to integer give `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`. If you prefer SQL, the equivalent is:

```
df.select([fn.expr('SUM(CAST(({c} IS NULL) AS INT)) AS {c}'.format(c=c)) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

or nicer, without a cast:

```
df.select([fn.expr('SUM(IF({c} IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS {c}'.format(c=c)) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

Comment: thank your for your help, yours and Karlsons solutions really helped to shine some light in the errors i was making in re: to my approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of `NULL` values per column you could count the non-null values and subtract from the total.

For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()


df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        (1, None),
        (1, 1),
        (None, None),
        (1, 1),
        (None, 1),
        (1, None),
    ],
    schema=("A", "B")
)

total = df.count()
missing_counts = df.select(
    *[(total - fn.count(col)).alias("missing(%s)" % col) for col in df.columns]
)

missing_counts.show()
>>> +----------+----------+
... |missing(A)|missing(B)|
... +----------+----------+
... |         2|         3|
... +----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this feedback; using a total and then subtracing from it can be quite useful for some of my other validating methods. does the `*` make a difference in this setting?

Comment: No, it shouldn't make a difference. @sgvd has a good point about this leading to evaluation twice, though.